# Random numbers, if, else if

Tags: javascript

Im writing JavaScript code like this:

```
function rollTrigger() {
var roll = Math.round(Math.random()*999999999+1);
var result = document.getElementById("result");

if (roll <= 50900000) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category 0";
    BoLPamount += 1;
    document.getElementById("boxlesserprizes").innerHTML = "Box of Lesser Prizes " + BoLPamount; 
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category 0"; //LOG        
} else if (roll <= 900000) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category A";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category A"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 360000) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category B";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category B"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 211890) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category C";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category C"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 109020) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category D";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category D"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 56505) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category E";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category E"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 34888) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category F";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category F"; //LOG
} else if (roll <= 15574) {
    result.innerHTML = "Category G";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category G"; //LOG
} else {
    result.innerHTML = "MEH";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = false"; //LOG
};
document.getElementById("roll").innerHTML = roll;
```

};

But it's not working properly... For example if the random number is 40200000 then it shows the "Category 0" as supposed to, however even if the random number is 10 it still shows "Category 0" instead of "Category G". Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: This should help solve this, and similar, problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger

Comment: Take a value for `roll`, say `10`, and execute the code in your head as you read it, line by line. What happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if (roll <= 50900000)`
Well 10 is smaller than 50900000, isn't it?
Reverse the order of the if-statements and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Because with number 10 it will enter the first condition since if (10 <= 50900000) is true.

You have to specify the range.

```
if(roll > 900000 && roll <= 50900000)
```

or start with the lower condition up to the highest

```
 if (roll <= 15574) 
 {
    result.innerHTML = "Category F";
    log.innerHTML += "<br />Trigger - win = true; Category F"; //LOG
 }
 else if (roll <= 34888) 
   {
     ...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You have to order your `if` tests so that they are in the correct order.  If they are all using `<=`, then you need to start by comparing to the lowest value and then the next higher value and so on.  Otherwise, it matches a higher number than you want.

Personally, I'd suggest a table driven approach rather than a zillion `if/else` tests.

```
var rollTests = [
    {value: 15574, resultHTML: "Category G", logHTML: "<br />Trigger - win = true", logHTML: "Category G"},
    {value: 34888, resultHTML: "Category F", logHTML: "<br />Trigger - win = true", logHTML: "Category F"},
    // the rest of the values here ordered by the comparison value ....
];

for (var i = 0, len = rollTests.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (roll <= rollTests[i].value) {
        result.innerHTML = rollTests[i].resultHTML;
        log.innerHTML = rollTests[i].logHTML;
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even more compact:

```
var rollTests = [
    {value: 15574, category: "G"},
    {value: 34888, category: "F"},
    // the rest of the values here ordered by the comparison value ....
];

var logHTML;    
for (var i = 0, len = rollTests.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (roll <= rollTests[i].value) {
        logHTML = "Category " + rollTests[i].category;
        log.innerHTML = logHTML;
        result.innerHTML = "<br />Trigger - win = true; " + logHTML;
        break;
    }
}
```